# What is a good way to write a django class-based view that both shows a date-based object and a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

What is the best way to write a class based view that both shows a date-based object and a form? The use case is a site index page view that both displays today's object and has a contact form.

At first I thought of using TodayArchiveView and [ContactFormView](https://github.com/madisona/django-contact-form) as mixins for my site index page view. However, TodayArchiveView inherits from BaseDateListView, and ContactFormView inherits from ProcessFormView. Both ProcessFormView and BaseDateListView implement get() and ultimately call render_to_response with very different data, so I'm thinking this won't work because even if I could call both through super, which would be returned? (I'm not even sure my thinking on this is correct; I'm still wrapping my head around multi-inheritance.)

Then I thought of writing my own get() that combines the functionality of the two gets, since their functionality doesn't collide, as far as I can tell. So that ended up looking like:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    self.date_list, self.object_list, extra_context = self.get_dated_items()
    context = self.get_context_data(form=form, object_list=self.object_list,
        date_list=self.date_list)
    context.update(extra_context)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Is this the right approach?

As a larger question, how do you know which mixins can be used with each other? I had to go to the django source to realize that both classes were implementing get().

Comment: Experimentally, I've confirmed that this approach works. Still wondering if it is right, conceptually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your form related to the object or not? From the description it seems it isn't, and I'm guessing that your contact form is in some kind of a sidebar or a similar site-wide (or at least a section-wide) element.

If that is correct I wouldn't include the form in the view at all; instead, I would use a tag or an include or a similar method to place a separately-defined template.

Comment: You're right, it's not intrinsic to the index view, but part of the sidebar. An inclusion tag makes a lot of sense.